# Contar registros agrupados con mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta tabla en mysql

```html
<table border="2">
 <tr>
 <td>id_producto</td>
 <td>id_sabor</td>
 <td>stock</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>16</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>15</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>29</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>4</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>30</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>5</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>30</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>6</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>30</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>7</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>30</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>8</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>30</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>9</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>30</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>30</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>11</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>30</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>12</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>8</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>13</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>13</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>14</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>15</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>15</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>10</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>16</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>17</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>0</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>18</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>14</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>19</td>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>0</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>19</td>
 <td>4</td>
 <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>19</td>
 <td>5</td>
 <td>0</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>19</td>
 <td>6</td>
 <td>0</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>19</td>
 <td>7</td>
 <td>0</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>19</td>
 <td>8</td>
 <td>1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>19</td>
 <td>9</td>
 <td>0</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>19</td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>0</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>19</td>
 <td>11</td>
 <td>10</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>20</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>26</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>21</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>29</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>22</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>19</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>23</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>24</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>24</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>12</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>25</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>10</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>26</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>27</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>12</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>34</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>18</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>35</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>19</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>36</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>13</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>37</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>38</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>20</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Lo que necesito es una consulta que me cuente el total de productos que tengan el stock mayor o igual a 1, en la tabla hay productos que se repiten porque son productos que tienen diferentes sabores con su respectivo stock, para este caso solo seria tomar el producto por ejemplo tengo este código:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(COUNT(*)) AS total FROM almacen WHERE stock >= 1
```

El resultado que me devuelve es 33 pero lo correcto seria 31, como podría solucionar esto?

Comment: Creo que estas al revés.. prueba `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT *)`

Comment: Gracias me funcionó

Comment: Entonces lo explico como respuesta para que puedas marcarla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error estaba donde pensaba.
Estabas haciendo el DISTINCT al revés.

La manera correcta de hacerlo es:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_producto)) AS total FROM almacen WHERE stock >= 1
```

El problema acá, es a QUIEN le estás ejecutando el DISTINCT, que se debe hacer a las columnas, y no al COUNT.

Comment: Bueno agrego como comentario, puse así como lo mencionas SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT *) AS total ...... pero me marcaba error, lo que hice entonces fue agregar id_producto dentro del DISTINCT, SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_producto)) AS total ..... y así me funcionó correctamente

Comment: Perfecto !!! corregire eso en el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(idAlmacen) as Total
from almacen
where stock >= 1
group by idAlmacen;
```

Se cuenta por el **campo idAlmacen**, este campo sería el **campo llave** de la tabla que se autoincrementa automáticamente y no se repite, yo le puse **idAlmacen**, alomejor tu le pusiste otro nombre, y se hace un **group by** por este mismo campo el cual agrupará todos los **idAlmacen**, haciendo posible el conteo del **select**.